# SQL is getting the product from 4 categories even though I am using distinct?? help

Tags: sql, asp-classic, distinct

Thanks for looking. 
I am grabbing products from an mdb which are marked as being "hotdeal" but each product is in several categories and it is showing each one 4 times!! Can anyone see where I have cocked up? 
many Thanks....

```
pHotDeal = getUserInput(request.querystring("hotDeal"),2)

mySql="SELECT DISTINCT products.idProduct, sku, description, price, visits, listPrice, length, width, height, smallImageUrl, sales, dateAdded, isBundleMain, rental, map, freeShipping, stock.stock, emailText, deliveringtime FROM products, stock, categories_products WHERE listHidden=0 AND active=-1 AND user1 is null AND idStore=" &pIdStore& " AND products.idStock=stock.idStock AND products.idProduct=categories_products.idProduct" 

' hot deal
if pHotDeal<>"" then
 mySQL=mySQL&" AND hotDeal=-1"
end if
```

Why is it not "distinct-ing" ?? :)

Thanks anyone

Comment: Have you checked to make sure each of those fields is identical for the 4 rows?

Comment: @kevchadders 
Yes, there is only one product record, its just referenced from 4 different categories.

Comment: It depends on how many categories products you have per product

Comment: @teamplayer there are 4 per product. The table categories_product has two columns idproduct and idcategory. So product 285 is listed 4 times. 
idproduct - idcategory
285              116,
285              83,
285              95,
285              117. This means when people view the "table" , "dining set", "Chair", "Dining Room" category the item shows up in all.

Comment: you know this is vulnerable to sql injection, right?

Comment: as well as using teh sql antipattern of implicit joins

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Group By products.idProduct
```

Comment: At the End after the Where part

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The "sale" button didn't have a value for the querystring "orderby" . It seems that when I add an orderby value it only shows each product once. Sorry! I know I didn't past the orderby option by bit, I didn't think it had anything to do with it! 
SO the answer is - there was an empty querystring. 
Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score -1):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT products.idProduct,
                  sku,
                  description,
                  price,
                  visits,
                  listPrice,
                  LENGTH,
                  width,
                  height,
                  smallImageUrl,
                  sales,
                  dateAdded,
                  isBundleMain,
                  rental,
                  map,
                  freeShipping,
                  stock.stock,
                  emailText,
                  deliveringtime
    FROM products, stock, categories_products
   WHERE     listHidden = 0
         AND active = -1
         AND user1 IS NULL
         AND idStore = " &pIdStore& "
         AND products.idStock = stock.idStock
         AND products.idProduct = categories_products.idProduct
         AND categories_product.idCategory = ??
GROUP BY products.idProduct
```

You need a category id to get 1 row.

Comment: When I go to the deal page without any categories_product.idcategory I am trying to show all products which are marked as "hotdeal", from ANY categories.

Comment: Found the problem!!! The link I had added to the "sale" button didn't have an orderby= in the querystring. It seems that when I add an orderby it only shows each product once. Sorry! I know I didn't past the order by bit I didn't think was affecting it!

Comment: <hangs head in shame> Thank you very much for your help though!!

Comment: -1 for encouraging the use of the sql antipattern of implilcit joins